# How to transmit a UIWebView vertical scroll event to the parent view?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

I add a `UIWebView` instance in my `UITableiViewCell` instance as a subview, and the view's hierarchy is like :

```
UIView->UITableView->UITableiViewCell-> UIWebView
```

The problem is when I scroll vertically inside the web view, the parent tableview didn't scroll! I don' want to set `UIWebView`'s property `userInteractionEnabled = NO`, and I only want to scroll my web view in horizontal direction.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property of `contentSize` properly.

```
webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PREDEFEINED_WIDTH, HEIGHT_OF_YOUR_TABLE_CELL);
```

Comment: Touching the contentsize is never a good idea in a webview scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading local html text, you can disable vertical scrolling using below code.

```
                         <html>
                         <head>
                         <style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                         "body {overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;}\n"
                         "</style>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                         //your content
                         </body>
                         </html>.
```

Or set the frame size of your Webview to Content size. Setting the frame of UITableview based on UIwebview Content Size is bit difficult. You can still disable the Scrollview scrolling.

```
 UIView * v = [[webView subviews] lastObject];
 if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]) {
  if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(setScrollEnabled]) {
    [v setScrollEnabled:NO];
  }
  if ([v respondsToSelector:@selector(bounces)]) {
    [v bounces:NO];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried your first method, but it not work, and the second method is not I want, because I only want to disable vertical scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UIWebView and relay the scrollViewDidScroll event back to your parent view by using a custom delegate.

in MyWebView.h

```
@protocol MyWebViewScrollDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void) webViewDidScroll:(UIWebView *)theWebView;
@end


@interface MyWebView : UIWebView
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyWebViewScrollDelegate> scrollDelegate;
@end
```

in MyWebView.m

```
@implementation MyWebView

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    if (_scrollDelegate && [_scrollDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidScroll:)]) {
        [_scrollDelegate webViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}

@end
```

then in your parent view

```
MyWebView *v = [[MyWebView alloc]init];
v.scrollDelegate = self;
```

and

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //do whatever you want with the scrollview
}
```